# Fluid-mechanics: Scalar field associated with velocity field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, conservative-field, potential-flow

I have just started studying fluid mechanics (without a proper physics education :) and came across the following equation for incompressible steady-state fluids.
$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u} = 0
$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity vector field. Playing around with the meaning of the equation, it appeared to me that, if $\mathbf{u}$ is a conservative vector field, that there should be a scalar field $\phi$ associated with $\mathbf{u}$ for which
$$
\nabla^2\phi=0.
$$
I.e there is a relation to Poisson/Laplace equations. My question is: is my reasoning correct and if so, what would be the physical meaning of $\phi$, pressure?

Comment: This scalar is sometimes known as the [velocity potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_potential).  I don't know whether it has a meaningful interpretation, though.

Comment: Ah that's a useful link @MichaelSeifert. I was trying to parse the Navier-Stokes equation(s) which seems to be to me a statement of the form F=ma in disguise. Anyways the there is term referred to as the pressure gradient. It would therefore be rather logical to assume that the pressure gradient is more related to acceleration than to velocity, or not?